# Discord.py bot failing to send a message when the member is not in the JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def coincount(ctx,*, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    member_id = str(member.id)
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        coins = users[member_id]['coins']
        if member_id in users:
            if coins > 1:
                await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has {coins} coins.')
            if coins == 1:
                await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has {coins} coin.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has no coins.')
```

There is no traceback. The bot sends the appropriate message if the member is in the file but doesn't do anything if they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the member ID is not in your JSON file, then `coins = users[member_id]['coins']` will raise a `KeyError`.
You should move it inside the if statement.

It might not be raising a traceback because of the [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) in your [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error).